How to use query and flatten formula in google sheets with null & desc
I'm trying to get column A by order of 'desc' based off whether column B is empty. I would like all of column A cells that have empty column B cells to be at the bottom. If possible without any helper cells Sample image
Please see Sample sheet Sample Sheet

You can try with sorting instead of QUERY:
=SORT(A2:A,B2:B<>"",0)

And insert it into QUERY or TOCOL to get rid of the blank values:
=QUERY(SORT(A2:A,B2:B<>"",0),"WHERE Col1 is not null",)

=TOCOL(SORT(A2:A,B2:B<>"",0),1)


Martin, I updated the pic & sheet to show why I use flatten

I'm sorry, I still don't see why you need to use FLATTEN. Do you need to add up several ranges? With your given scenario you can use =QUERY(SORT(A2:B19,B2:B19<>"",0),"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col1 is not null order by Col 2 desc",) to have the sorting according to non empty in B and values in second column

In fact, you can just use: =QUERY(A2:B19,"SELECT A, B WHERE A is not null order by B desc",) - and empty values of B will go to the bottom. But if you need to stack different non consecutive ranges, because of subtotals, you can use VSTACK to generate an integrated range: =QUERY(VSTACK(A2:B16,A19:B19,A30:B35,A42:B57),"SELECT Col1, Col2 WHERE Col1 is not null order by Col2 desc",)

OMG thank you Martin the QUERY VSTACK is exactly what I needed. Will need to brush up on VSTACK. Thank you again

I'm glad it was useful! Consider marking the question as answered ;)
